# Gamepad left analog stick is not sensitive

Tags: controllers

I have a new gamepad (bought yesterday) that works fine except for one aspect: The left analog stick is not sensitive enough when moving it to the left. For some games, this is not a problem, but for the majority of the games (namely, the ones I tend to play) this is a daunting issue.

Here's a screenshot of testing on windows:
[image: The left analog stick is titled to the left. But not left enough.]

Comment: This sort of problem is normally caught during the calibration. Can't reach far left? -> Adjust signal so you can. So, did you calibrate it?

Comment: @MrLemon: This gamepad works on PS2 and Windows. So, this is your solution for Windows, thanks.

Comment: It would help to link what gamepad you're using. Several 3rd party controllers from China have varying qualities.

Comment: @MrLemon: How to adjust the signal to reach far left ? I tried calibration but it didn't work.

Comment: @Coreus: It is a highlink gamepad.